# how to set words from the sentence one below the other js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

Hi I have problem with my words in sentence. I have sentence, I do a loop to get words, and then I want to put them in `<li> -` one below the other. So i did again a loop to get only words, and put them to li, but in my page I have only one word. Why its happened like that?

```
const wordText = document.createElement("div");
const lettersSection = document.querySelector(".letter");
        wordText.classList.add("wordText");
        lettersSection.appendChild(wordText);
        const jokeText = document.querySelectorAll(".random_joke h3");
        for (let el of jokeText) {
            const matchWords = el.textContent.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
            const changeSequenceWords = matchWords.sort(byLength);
            // const newString = changeSequenceWords.join(" ");
            for (let el of changeSequenceWords ) {
                const word = el;
                console.log(el)
                wordText.innerHTML = `<h4>Words:</h4><span><li>${word}</li></span>`
            }
            // const newString = changeSequenceWords.join(" ");

            // wordText.innerHTML = `<h4>Words:</h4><span>${newString} </span>`
        }
```

Comment: `wordText.innerHTML` - this will overwrite everytime the loop is run. Better use a variable and keep on appending the `li`s and finally after the loop use `wordText.innerHTML = variable`

Comment: Also consider a data binding framework (like Svelte, Vue or React) so you can simply specify `matchWords` and the DOM updates itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're removing the old value of `wordText.innerHTML` each time the loop runs - use `+=`:

```
wordText.innerHTML += `<h4>Words:</h4><span><li>${word}</li></span>`
```

Comment: I did as you write, but now I have duplicate my words. Its mean, that first clik on button give me all words from sentence, but secon click give me all words from first sentence and all words from second sentence. I think something is wrong with loop, but I tried everything, and I can not find the problem :/